# Dataweave - How to transform array of items into parent child relation in Dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I want to convert the below input into parent-child JSON output using dataweave transform. Please let me know if anybody worked on this before. I've added a sample input and output json below.

Updated post with additional nodes: I want multiple parent nodes with location level=1 with respective hierarchies.

**Input json format:**

```
[
    {
        "ENTITY_ID": 1,
        "PARENT_EID": 1,
        "LOCATION_LEVEL": 1,
        "LOCATION_CODE": "123"
    },
    {
        "ENTITY_ID": 2,
        "PARENT_EID": 1,
        "LOCATION_LEVEL": 2,
        "LOCATION_CODE": "234"
    },
    {
        "ENTITY_ID": 3,
        "PARENT_EID": 2,
        "LOCATION_LEVEL": 3,
        "LOCATION_CODE": "345"
    },
    {
        "ENTITY_ID": 4,
        "PARENT_EID": 1,
        "LOCATION_LEVEL": 2,
        "LOCATION_CODE": "567"
    },
    {
        "ENTITY_ID": 5,
        "PARENT_EID": 5,
        "LOCATION_LEVEL": 1,
        "LOCATION_CODE": "012"
    },
    {
        "ENTITY_ID": 6,
        "PARENT_EID": 5,
        "LOCATION_LEVEL": 1,
        "LOCATION_CODE": "023"
    }
]
```

**Output json format:**

```
[
    {
        "ENTITY_ID": 1,
        "PARENT_EID": 1,
        "LOCATION_LEVEL": 1,
        "LOCATION_CODE": "123",
        "CHILDRENS":[
                {
                    "ENTITY_ID": 2,
                    "PARENT_EID": 1,
                    "LOCATION_LEVEL": 2,
                    "LOCATION_CODE": "234"
                    "CHILDRENS":[{
                            "ENTITY_ID": 3,
                            "PARENT_EID": 2,
                            "LOCATION_LEVEL": 3,
                            "LOCATION_CODE": "345"                          
                    }]
                },
                {
                    "ENTITY_ID": 4,
                    "PARENT_EID": 1,
                    "LOCATION_LEVEL": 2,
                    "LOCATION_CODE": "567"
                }
        ]
        
    },
    {
        "ENTITY_ID": 5,
        "PARENT_EID": 5,
        "LOCATION_LEVEL": 1,
        "LOCATION_CODE": "012",
        "CHILDRENS":[{
                  "ENTITY_ID": 6,
                  "PARENT_EID": 5,
                  "LOCATION_LEVEL": 2,
                  "LOCATION_CODE": "023"
              }]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var data = [
    {
        "ENTITY_ID": 1,
        "PARENT_EID": 1,
        "LOCATION_LEVEL": 1,
        "LOCATION_CODE": "123"
    },
    {
        "ENTITY_ID": 2,
        "PARENT_EID": 1,
        "LOCATION_LEVEL": 2,
        "LOCATION_CODE": "234"
    },
    {
        "ENTITY_ID": 3,
        "PARENT_EID": 2,
        "LOCATION_LEVEL": 3,
        "LOCATION_CODE": "345"
    },
    {
        "ENTITY_ID": 4,
        "PARENT_EID": 1,
        "LOCATION_LEVEL": 2,
        "LOCATION_CODE": "567"
    },
    {
        "ENTITY_ID": 5,
        "PARENT_EID": 5,
        "LOCATION_LEVEL": 1,
        "LOCATION_CODE": "012"
    },
    {
        "ENTITY_ID": 6,
        "PARENT_EID": 5,
        "LOCATION_LEVEL": 2,
        "LOCATION_CODE": "023"
    }
]

var top = data filter ($.LOCATION_LEVEL == 1)

fun insert(t,e) = t match {
    case {} -> e
    case tree if (tree.ENTITY_ID == e.PARENT_EID) -> do {
        var node = tree - "CHILDREN"
        var children = if (tree.CHILDREN?) (tree.CHILDREN + e) else [e]
        ---
        {(node),CHILDREN: children}
    }
    case tree if (tree.ENTITY_ID != e.PARENT_EID) -> do {
        var node = tree - "CHILDREN"
        var children = tree.CHILDREN map ($ insert e)
        ---
        {(node), (CHILDREN: children) if (not isEmpty(children))}
    }
    else -> $
}


---
top map (topnode) -> (
    (data -- top) orderBy $.ENTITY_ID reduce ((e, acc=topnode) -> acc insert e)
)
```

Test it with more inputs and you may need to adjust the code if some other test cases fail.

You (or maybe someone else) may want to rewrite this using the `update` operator as compared building the `node` and the `children` variables like I do.

Comment: Its working upto 8 level of child nodes. howeer when  i try to insert child node for 4th parent, its failing. Thanks for your answer it means a lot

Comment: Isolate the record that causes the issue, then inspect it and replicate the behavior in your sample data.  It will also be useful if you provide the error message you get.

Comment: In case of again starting from location_level 1 means a new hierarchy, such type of senario its not working like new Location level 1

Comment: What if i have another node of location leavel 1 as below {
        "ENTITY_ID": 2,
        "PARENT_EID": 2,
        "LOCATION_LEVEL": 1,
        "LOCATION_CODE": "156"
    }

Comment: OK so we don't go back and forth, you need to provide sample data that capture all permutations.  Then you need to amend your original post to contain the sample data.  Additionally, you MUST provide with the algorithmic details (i.e. logic) on how you associate parent and child nodes.  Then and only then I will be able to assist further.

Comment: Just updated my question with additional nodes. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Please note using your dataweave expression, i am not getting array of hierarchical data like in [ ] brackets. Its in {} brackets. Thanks again :)

Comment: Also please note this is sample data, In actual data there are around 5000 list of nodes which i am transforming. I am getting Java.lang.stackoverflow error. Is there any way to optimize this?

Comment: About logic, its solelly based on parent eid and Entity id relationship along with location level. If location level =1 then its parent node

Comment: Are you there George?

Comment: Yes I am Sandesh, but I am busy this week--I will propably look at it during the weekend.

Comment: Please double-check your sample data--it seems that the last record should have `LOCATION_LEVEL: 2`

Comment: Made the updates to the solution to reflect your latest sample data.  If the code still does not work on your real world data then chances are you are missing further permutations of your data, which I believe that I have given you a pretty good head start ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var Input = [
    {
        "ENTITY_ID": 1,
        "PARENT_EID": 1,
        "LOCATION_LEVEL": 1,
        "LOCATION_CODE": "123"
    },
    {
        "ENTITY_ID": 2,
        "PARENT_EID": 1,
        "LOCATION_LEVEL": 2,
        "LOCATION_CODE": "234"
    },
    {
        "ENTITY_ID": 3,
        "PARENT_EID": 2,
        "LOCATION_LEVEL": 3,
        "LOCATION_CODE": "345"
    },
    {
        "ENTITY_ID": 4,
        "PARENT_EID": 1,
        "LOCATION_LEVEL": 2,
        "LOCATION_CODE": "567"
    },
    {
        "ENTITY_ID": 5,
        "PARENT_EID": 5,
        "LOCATION_LEVEL": 1,
        "LOCATION_CODE": "012"
    },
    {
        "ENTITY_ID": 6,
        "PARENT_EID": 5,
        "LOCATION_LEVEL": 2,
        "LOCATION_CODE": "023"
    }
]



fun hasChildren(id) = sizeOf(Input filter (($.PARENT_EID == id) and ($.ENTITY_ID != $.PARENT_EID)))

fun createTree(data) = if(hasChildren(data.ENTITY_ID) > 0)data ++ {"CHILDRENS": (Input filter (($.PARENT_EID == data.ENTITY_ID) and ($.ENTITY_ID != $.PARENT_EID))) map ((item, index) -> createTree(item)) } else data
---
Input filter ($.ENTITY_ID == $.PARENT_EID) map ((item, index) -> createTree(item))
```